# Check if an Array contains an Integer or not using for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an array, and use a for loop to check if that array contains an input integer or not by this code:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class playGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int guess;
        int[] range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).toArray(); // Set the range from 1 - 100
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(range));

        System.out.println("Please type a number ");
        guess = TextIO.getlnInt();
        for(int i:range) { // Check if input value is in range or not
            if( i == guess){
                System.out.println("good job");
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

This works quite well; However, when I:

1. Replace `( i == guess)` with `(i != guess) // if guess not in range`. Java always prints "good job" whether input integer in range 1-100 or not.
2. When I add an else statement like `else { System,out.println("terrible"); }` or use `break;` to break the loop;
   It always prints "terrible" or print the whether integer in range or not.
3. How can I ask people for input integer again if it's not in range 1-100. Should I use the nested loop, or is there anyway simpler?

Please help me with these 3 problems.

Comment: Edit your post and paste your full code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

not using an array and a for loop will solve all your issues. try

```
if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 100) {
    System.out.println("good job");
} else {
    System.out.println("terrible");
}
```

1) let's assume guess == 10. Your for loop will print "good job" 99 times. Because 10 != 1, 10 != 2, 10 == 10, 10 != 100.

2) because guess is != i 99 times again.

3) use a while ( true ) loop and a break after printing "good job".

Comment: Thank you, I got the problem for 1 and 2. Well, in this example I have number 1 and 100, but if the I just have a range without knowing it's bound? A random one or get it from input?

Comment: that does not matter. It's the same if you run IntStream.rangeClosed(a, b) (with a & b the range limits) or if (guess >= a && guess <= b). You have to know a and b and use them somewhere in the code whether it is for creating an array or in an if clause. Get a and b first, then use it.

Comment: another advantage of using an if clause is that you can use a float value as input. You'll not be able to create an array with all floats from 1 to 100

Comment: OK. It seems that finding the boundary and an If statement is really the simplest way. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build up a `java.util.HashSet` upon the array values, and use it to check easily if a given number is contained within them.

```
Set<Integer> mySet=new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(range));
boolean guessIsContained=mySet.contains(guess);
```

And if you want to loop a user input until a guess is OK, you'd enclose the whole operation within a `while` with a proper exit condition:

```
Set<Integer> mySet=...
do
{
     // ... input one guess from user.
     boolean guessIsContained=mySet.contains(guess);
     // ... evaluate guessIsContained

} while (!guessIsContained);
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot add the type argument Integer after new HashSet? And the result is always False wheter the guess is in range 1-100 or not?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, for `i` to equal `guess`, i needs to be in range anyway...I find that contradictory. Anyway, to do it without a for loop:

```
 if(1<=i<=100 && i == guess){
            System.out.println("good job");

}
```

If `1<=i<=100`, then it is in range. That makes the for loop an if statement, and I combined it with your other if statement, and put `&& i == guess`.

1) Should work with the above code

2)I don't understand what your saying, but from the official java docs:

> An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for,
>   while, or do-while statement, but a labeled break terminates an outer
>   statement.

3) Try the following:

```
if(1<=i<=100 && i == guess){
                System.out.println("good job");

    }else if(i<1 || i>100)
 System.out.println("Please type a number in range");
    guess = TextIO.getlnInt();
```